# Перевод длинных имен формата Windows в формат DOS

Tags: windows, файловая-система, dos

По каким правилам переводятся длинные имена формата Windows в формат DOS? Сначала имя обрезается до 6 знаков, ставится тильда и номер файла из файлов с одинаковыми началами имён; но это до 4-х имён, а далее идёт какая-то непонятная 16-ричная кодировка!

Comment: А можете привести пример? (Кстати, интересно, зачем вам?)

Answer (score 1):

При особом желании короткое имя может назначаться явно, поэтому пытаться его вычислить самостоятельно - это плохая идея. Там иногда даже кириллица остаётся, а не заменяется на коды символов. И не только кириллица.

Для получения короткого имени по полному следует воспользоваться функцией `GetShortPathName` из `kernel32`. Обращаю внимание, что надо пользоваться юникодной функцией, ибо есть ситуации, когда неюникодная скажет, что имени не существует из-за наличия в нём некоторых символов, а юникодная нормально предоставит имя файла (есть реальный пример такого поведения). Нельзя рассчитывать, что имя будет использовать только asсii-символы.

Answer (score 0):

[Как Windows создает имен файлов 8.3 из длинных имен файлов](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/142982)
 и вот еще: [Что такое файл](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/29226914).

Comment: Здесь описано только то, что я и так знаю. Почему-то даже на сайте майкрософт не описано - что делается с именами, если похожих имён файлов больше 4-х.

Comment: Или у меня винда с необычной файлсистемой? У кого-нибудь из программистов была похожая проблема?

Comment: Я написал программу на QBasic'е для пакетного конвертирования текстовых файлов из кодировки UTF-8 в ASCII. Пути задаются в файле настроек. Хочу, чтобы программа распознавала длинные пути путём перевода их в короткие. Получается только если файлов с похожими именами не больше 4-х. На остальные выходит ошибка.

Comment: 123456~1.TXT 123456789-01.txt
123456~2.TXT 123456789-02.txt
123456~3.TXT 123456789-03.txt
123456~4.TXT 123456789-04.txt
12D2DE~1.TXT 123456789-05.txt
12D2D2~1.TXT 123456789-06.txt
12D2D6~1.TXT 123456789-07.txt
12E2DA~1.TXT 123456789-08.txt
12E2DE~1.TXT 123456789-09.txt
12C6DA~1.TXT 123456789-10.txt
12C6DE~1.TXT 123456789-11.txt
12C6D2~1.TXT 123456789-12.txt
12C6D6~1.TXT 123456789-13.txt
12D6DA~1.TXT 123456789-14.txt
12D6DE~1.TXT 123456789-15.txt
12D6D2~1.TXT 123456789-16.txt